# GLTF Object loading but not showing up

Tags: three.js, gltf

I'm using three.js and have the scene and everything set up but when I try to load a 3d object (.gltf from here [sketchfab 3d object](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/laptop-7d870e900889481395b4a575b9fa8c3e#download)). But the object seems to load fully and then doesn't show up for some reason. The file is being imported correctly.

```
import laptop from './laptop/scene.gltf'

var objloader = new GLTFLoader();               
    objloader.load(laptop, function (gltf) {
        gltf.scene.scale.set(2, 2, 2);
        gltf.scene.position.set(220, 10, 400)

        scene.add(gltf.scene);
    });
```

This error is showing up in the console which doesn't make sense because it should be placed correctly.

```
RangeError: attempting to construct out-of-bounds TypedArray on ArrayBuffer
```

Comment: Are you using the latest version of `three.js`?  Also make sure not to use a `GLTFLoader` from a third-party npm package.

Comment: Version 121 and I'm importing it from the examples `import {GLTFLoader} from '../../../../node_modules/three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader';`

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this problem by converting the gltf to glb. The gltf folder had textures folder inside as well as a binary file. Perhaps React was not taking those extra files into account. Because glb is the entire 3d object inside one file with no dependencies.